# How to disable PytestDeprecationWarning: direct construction of Flake8Item has been deprecated, please use Flake8Item.from_parent

Tags: python, pytest, flake8

- When I run `python setup.py test` command in my project folder to test my package with `setup.cfg` configuration I got this warning message.
- How can I disable it?

> `python setup.py test` acts like `pytest --flake8` command.

```
============================================================================================== warnings summary =============================================================================================== 
c:\users\yedhrab\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest_flake8.py:65
  c:\users\yedhrab\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest_flake8.py:65: PytestDeprecationWarning: direct construction of Flake8Item has been deprecated, please use Flake8Item.from_parent
    return Flake8Item(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
=========================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================== 
SKIPPED [1] c:\users\***\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pytest_flake8.py:106: file(s) previously passed FLAKE8 checks
=================================================================================== 9 passed, 1 skipped, 1 warning in 0.33s ===================================================================================
```

Comment: Please don't "tag" your title. That's what... _tags_ are for. And _definitely_ please don't pollute it with emoji. _Very_ occasional, judicious use of emoji might be acceptable, depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about tags. And for Emojis: Emojies makes context more understandable because our brain is more effective to understand image when you compare it to ugly lineer text. Emojies effect emotion and if you don't feel any emotion when you learn something, you will probably forget it.

Comment: [Here is a meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342068/354577) encouraging users to edit excessive emoji out. There isn't a clear rule about it, but systems allowing users to edit each others' content are there for a reason.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to disable all warnings but only a specific pytest warning, use the `-W` parameter:

```
pytest -W ignore::pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `--disable-warnings` flag to silence the warnings for a particular test if that's really what you want.

```sh
pytest --disable-warnings
```

See for more details by running `pytest --help`.

Comment: I was not able to supress warning with this option.  `-W ignore::pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning` works correctly

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue via adding these lines to my `setup.cfg`

```
[tool:pytest]
# ...
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```